# Mac OS X PHP 5.4.29 compile error "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64"

Tags: php, macos, compilation

Trying to compile PHP 5.4.29 on Mac OS X 10.8.4

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr  --mandir=/usr/share/man  --infodir=/usr/share/info
--sysconfdir=/private/etc  --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs  --enable-cli
--with-config-file-path=/etc  --with-libxml-dir=/usr  --with-openssl=/usr
--with-kerberos=/usr  --with-zlib=/usr  --enable-bcmath  --with-bz2=/usr
--enable-calendar  --with-curl=/usr  --enable-dba  --enable-exif  --enable-ftp
--with-gd  --enable-gd-native-ttf  --with-icu-dir=/usr  --with-iodbc=/usr
--with-ldap=/usr  --with-ldap-sasl=/usr  --with-libedit=/usr  --enable-mbstring
--enable-mbregex  --with-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd  --without-pear
--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock
--with-readline=/usr  --enable-shmop  --with-snmp=/usr  --enable-soap
--enable-sockets  --enable-sysvmsg  --enable-sysvsem  --enable-sysvshm
--with-tidy  --enable-wddx  --with-xmlrpc  --with-iconv-dir=/usr
--with-xsl=/usr  --enable-zip  --with-pcre-regex  --with-pgsql=/usr
--with-pdo-pgsql=/usr --with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11  --with-png-dir=/usr/X11
```

then doing **make** and getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ap_get_server_version", referenced from:
      _zif_apache_get_version in php_functions.o
      _zm_info_apache in php_functions.o
  "_ap_log_error", referenced from:
      _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
      _php_apache_sapi_log_message in sapi_apache2.o
  "_ap_log_rerror", referenced from:
      _php_handler in sapi_apache2.o
      _php_apache_sapi_log_message in sapi_apache2.o
  "_unixd_config", referenced from:
      _zm_info_apache in php_functions.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [libs/libphp5.bundle] Error 1
```

Anyone seen this before? Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Could you show the commands you used to build, any prefixes etc...

Comment: I edited my question to show my "configure" options.

Comment: The undefined symbols are present in the Apache logging core. I don't know if you already have Apache installed, but I feel like this could be the problem; the linker cannot find the references, a certain header or library needs to be included. Perhaps just try a generic `configure && make` to see if the same error occurs.

Comment: I've quickly read through the PHP manual. What you have looks right to me `--with-apxs2` is definitely pointing to the correct binary?

Comment: I tried **--with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs** because this file has the same date as my /usr/sbin/httpd, but still got the same errors.  BTW, generic **configure && make** worked just fine.  I think I'll try compiling PHP 5.5.13 (current stable) to see if it works, and if so, I may just stick with it.

Comment: OK glad to hear the generic build worked for you, as stated the core of your build looks fine, there are a lot of custom arguments though which could be causing an issue. Divide and conquer if you feel up to it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I got it working. I was getting nowhere so I've decided to first upgrade to **Mavericks** (10.9.3). I was still getting errors while trying to compile PHP, although they were different from the original error I was getting under Mountain Lion.

First, I needed to make sure the Command Line Tools were installed after OS upgrade.  For some reason my Xcode 5.1.1 doesn't give me this option in "Preferences" anymore, so I (re)installed Command Line Tools in shell:

```
xcode-select --install
```

I set some environment variables to compile Apache and PHP:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe -no-cpp-precomp"
CCFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
CXXFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -Os -pipe"
LDFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -bind_at_load"
export CFLAGS CXXFLAGS LDFLAGS CCFLAGS MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
```

Then I compiled and installed **apr** and **apr-util** which are available on apr.apache.org.  Then compiled and installed Apache 2.4.9:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-layout=Darwin --enable-cgi --enable-ssl --enable-so --enable-rewrite --enable-mime-magic --enable-suexec --enable-modules=all --enable-mods-shared=all --with-apr=/usr/local/apr --with-apr-util=/usr/local/apr 
make
make install
```

Then PHP 5.5.13:

```
./configure  --prefix=/usr  --mandir=/usr/share/man  --infodir=/usr/share/info  --sysconfdir=/private/etc  --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs  --enable-cli  --with-config-file-path=/etc  --with-libxml-dir=/usr  --with-openssl=/usr  --with-kerberos=/usr  --with-zlib=/usr  --enable-bcmath  --with-bz2=/usr  --enable-calendar  --with-curl=/usr  --enable-dba  --enable-exif  --enable-ftp  --with-gd  --enable-gd-native-ttf  --with-icu-dir=/usr  --with-ldap=/usr  --with-ldap-sasl=/usr  --with-libedit=/usr  --enable-mbstring  --enable-mbregex  --with-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysqli=mysqlnd  --without-pear  --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd  --with-mysql-sock=/var/mysql/mysql.sock  --with-readline=/usr  --enable-shmop  --with-snmp=/usr  --enable-soap  --enable-sockets  --enable-sysvmsg  --enable-sysvsem  --enable-sysvshm  --with-tidy  --enable-wddx  --with-xmlrpc  --with-iconv-dir=/usr  --with-xsl=/usr  --enable-zip  --with-pcre-regex  --with-freetype-dir=/usr/X11  --with-png-dir=/usr/X11 --with-jpeg-dir=/usr
make
make install
```

Then restored my old php.ini and httpd.conf files, restarted apache, and it worked for me.  These are major steps, but there were smaller things along the way I needed to install because I was getting missing libraries/files errors.  For example, before I could compile PHP, I needed to compile and install Libjpeg.  I used **jpegsrc.v9a.tar.gz** downloaded from http://www.ijg.org/files/.

I don't know if above steps would work equally well for Mountain Lion.